# SQLite Java: table Y has no column named X in "INSERT INTO Y

Tags: java, android, sqlite

antes de nada, ya he visto que existen preguntas parecidas a la mia en el foro, pero no he encontrado respuestas en ellas.

Estoy aprendiendo a usar SQLite con java para android y al intentar registrar en una base de datos me sale el tipico error:

> table articulos has no column named nombre in "INSERT INTO
> articulos(codigo,nombre,precio)

Y me estoy rompiendo la cabeza, porque pone que no existe una columna llamada "nombre" en una tabla articulos con las columnas: codigo, nombre, precio.

El propio error indica que sí que existe esa columna.

Aqui el codigo de creación de la columna

```
 baseDeDatos.execSQL("create table articulos(codigo int primary key, nombre text , precio real)");
```

Gracias de antemano.

El error aparece al llamar a este metodo

```
 public void Registrar (View view){

    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase baseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String codigo, nombre, precio;

    codigo = et_codigo.getText().toString();
    nombre = et_nombre.getText().toString();
    precio = et_precio.getText().toString();

    if(!codigo.isEmpty() && !nombre.isEmpty() && !precio.isEmpty()){

        ContentValues registro =new  ContentValues();

        registro.put("codigo", codigo);
        registro.put("nombre", nombre);
        registro.put("precio", precio);

        baseDeDatos.insert("articulos", null, registro);

        baseDeDatos.close();

        et_codigo.setText("");
        et_nombre.setText("");
        et_precio.setText("");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Registro guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Deberías poner el código donde aparece el error

Comment: ¿Tu tabla ya fue modificada? es decir si tuviste una version en la cual no tenías el campo nombre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a el problema que expones

> Y me estoy rompiendo la cabeza, porque pone que no existe una columna
> llamada "nombre" en una tabla articulos con las columnas: codigo,
> nombre, precio.

y revisando que el Query para crear la tabla es correcto e incluye el campo nombre:

```
 baseDeDatos.execSQL("create table articulos(codigo int primary key, nombre text , precio real)");
```

El problema se debe a que seguramente a que inicialmente se creo una estructura incorrecta que no contenía el campo nombre, para solucionar esto, elimina el caché de la app o elimina la aplicación e instalala nuevamente.

Comment: Efectivamente el problema viene de aqui, ya que la tabla fue modificada porque estaba mal estructurada, eliminé el caché y todo bien. Muchas gracias!